# Conecting MySQL on Azure with WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure

I have created an **Azure Database for MySQL** following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-portal) from Microsoft and it is working fine. When I use the same credentials in a Wordpress website, the site displays "**Error establishing a database connection**" error.

I have tested the same credentials using MySQL workbench on my local machine it works. Any ideas?

**Sample credentials:**

```
define('DB_NAME', 'my_blog');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'my_usr@server-mysql');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'server-mysql.mysql.database.azure.com');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Comment: Ensure to provide wordpress website access to database. Add IP address to list of allowed connections for MySQL Database instance.  To know which IP address your Azure WordPress site is using you can use the steps outlined here (the IP addresses are actually in the properties of the Azure App Service): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/02/01/how-do-i-determine-the-outbound-ip-addresses-of-my-azure-app-service/

Open the MySQL instance in the Azure Portal and click the “Connection security” tab. From there add the IP addresses your WordPress site is running on.

Comment: For testing, Firewall is set to all IPs